# How do I add the row update time and row update user to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a create date and create user field defined that appears to be working.

But I'm having difficulty with creating a properly functioning Row Update Date Time and Row Updated by fields.

How I would like the fields to work: when someone UPDATEs a record in the table, the date/time and username is recorded for **only** the records being updated.

Here's my failing Trigger Creation Syntax, which I've incorrectly adapted from answers seen on Stack Overflow:

I should note, that I don't understand where the 'inserted' table came from in so many other examples. Nor why it and the inner join works.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mkt.Update_tbl_fTesting
  ON mkt.tbl_fTesting
  FOR UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE mkt.tbl_fTesting
    SET RowUpdateDateTime = GetDate()
      , RowUpdateBy = coalesce(SUSER_SNAME(), '?')
    FROM mkt.tbl_fTesting
    INNER JOIN inserted
    ON tbl_fTesting.tbl_fTestingIdentity = inserted.ID;
END
GO
```

The error on executing the trigger creation syntax is:

> Invalid Column Name 'ID'

Here's my working as expected table creation syntax:

```
USE [ObscuredDatabase]
GO

DROP TABLE [mkt].[tbl_fTesting]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [mkt].[tbl_fTesting](
    [tbl_TestingIdentity] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
  [Produce] [nvarchar] (25) NOT NULL,
  [Color] [nvarchar] (25) NOT NULL,
  [RowCreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
  [RowCreateBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL DEFAULT (coalesce(suser_sname(),'?')),
  [RowUpdateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
  [RowUpdateBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [tbl_fTestingIdentity] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [SECONDARY]
) ON [SECONDARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should note, that I don't understand where the 'inserted' table came
>   from in so many other examples. Nor why it and the inner join works.

You're real close.  Think of the `inserted` table as a temporary table that is holding the records that will be inserted or updated.  It has the same structure as the table receiving the update.

So all you need to do is use the correct column name from the `inserted` table, which will match the column name of `mkt.tbl_fTesting`, in your `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mkt.Update_tbl_fTesting
  ON mkt.tbl_fTesting
  FOR UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE FTest
    SET RowUpdateDateTime = GetDate()
      , RowUpdateBy = coalesce(SUSER_SNAME(), '?')
    FROM mkt.tbl_fTesting FTest
    INNER JOIN inserted
    ON FTest.tbl_fTestingIdentity = inserted.tbl_fTestingIdentity;
END
GO
```

**EDIT** more info:

Imagine a simple table, `Clothes`:

```
ID | Type  | Color | RowUpdateDateTime
1  | Sock  | Pink  | NULL
2  | Sock  | Red   | NULL
3  | Shirt | Blue  | NULL
```

And you run a simple update:

```
UPDATE Clothes
SET    Color = 'Green'
WHERE  Type = 'Sock'
```

At execution time, an `inserted` table will be created, and will contain the new rows:

```
ID | Type  | Color | RowUpdateDateTime
1  | Sock  | Green | NULL
2  | Sock  | Green | NULL
```

Your trigger will then fire off the update to the `RowUpdateDateTime` column:

```
UPDATE C
SET RowUpdateDateTime = GETDATE()
FROM Clothes C
INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.ID = C.ID;
```

Which because of the join predicate `i.ID = C.ID`, will *only change the modified date of the rows affected by the original update*

Final `Clothes` table:

```
ID | Type  | Color | RowUpdateDateTime
1  | Sock  | Green | 2017-05-09 16:32:09.873
2  | Sock  | Green | 2017-05-09 16:32:09.873
3  | Shirt | Blue  | NULL
```

Comment: So does this mean that the inserted table would essentially have one row at the moment of the update?

Comment: @ChrisG Not quite.. it will have the same number of rows that are being updated by the original update.  This is why you have to actually join to it on a condition.  To link X number of original rows to the X number of inserted rows.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It makes a little bit of sense, but I'll just need to do some independent reading and research. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisG Happy to help.  I added a little more explanation as well.  GL to you.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the primary key of your table is not called `ID`, is called `tbl_TestingIdentity` so in the inserted you need to use this column name. `(inserted.tbl_TestingIdentity)`

Comment: Thank you Rigerta, your answer is absolutely correct and worked for me